# Download entire history of a Wikipedia page

Tags: python, web-scraping, wikipedia

I'd like to download the entire revision history of a single article on Wikipedia, but am running into a roadblock.

It is very easy to download an entire Wikipedia article, or to grab pieces of its history using the [Special:Export](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Parameters_to_Special:Export) URL parameters:

```
curl -d "" 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:Export&pages=Stack_Overflow&limit=1000&offset=1' -o "StackOverflow.xml"
```

And of course I can download the **entire** site including all versions of every article from [here](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Data_dumps), but that's many terabytes and way more data than I need.

Is there a pre-built method for doing this? (Seems like there must be.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wandering around aimlessly looking for clues to another question I have myself — my way of saying I know nothing substantial about this topic! — I just came upon this a moment after reading your  question: http://mwclient.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/page.html. Have a look for the `revisions` method.

EDIT: I also see http://mwclient.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/page-ops.html#listing-page-revisions.

Sample code using the `mwclient` module:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import logging, mwclient, pickle, os
from mwclient import Site
from mwclient.page import Page
logging.root.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

logging.debug('getting page...')
env_page = os.getenv("MEDIAWIKI_PAGE")
page_name = env_page is not None and env_page or 'Stack Overflow'
page_name = Page.normalize_title(env_page)
site = Site('en.wikipedia.org') # https by default. change w/`scheme=`
page = site.pages[page_name]

logging.debug('extracting revisions (may take a really long time, depending on the page)...')
revisions = []
for i, revision in enumerate(page.revisions()):
    revisions.append(revision)

logging.debug('saving to file...')
with open('{}Revisions.mediawiki.pkl'.format(page_name), 'wb+') as f:
    pickle.dump(revisions, f, protocol=0) # protocol allows backwards compatibility between machines
```

Comment: This is great, thanks Bill! Adding some sample code to your answer, for completeness.

Comment: You're welcome, and good work! I was just about to add some myself.

Answer (score 6):

The example above only gets information about the revisions, not the actual contents themselves. Here's a short python script that downloads the full content and metadata history data of a page into individual json files:

```
import mwclient
import json
import time

site = mwclient.Site('en.wikipedia.org')
page = site.pages['Wikipedia']

for i, (info, content) in enumerate(zip(page.revisions(), page.revisions(prop='content'))):
    info['timestamp'] = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", info['timestamp'])
    print(i, info['timestamp'])
    open("%s.json" % info['timestamp'], "w").write(json.dumps(
        { 'info': info,
            'content': content}, indent=4))
```