# Download entire history of a Wikipedia page in HTML Format

Tags: web-scraping, mediawiki, wikipedia, wikipedia-api, wikidata

I want to download the entire revision history of a single article on Wikipedia in HTML format, thanks to this question [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45193005/download-entire-history-of-a-wikipedia-page), I am getting the entire history of a Wikipedia page in a JSON format but I want to get as a HTML format with images and everything.

I tried to convert to that json to other format but it did not work. Is there any way to doing this?

Comment: they may not have version HTML - they can keep in database all as JSON and generate HTML for last version when user load page in web browser. You may have to write own `HTML template` to generate HTML page. And this may not be easy.

Answer (score 1):

If you visit page then there is link `view history` which shows list of all previous versions and every version has link `curr` to display page which compares old version with current version.

Every link has `&diff=...&oldid=...` and if you remove `&diff=...` and keep `&oldid=...` then you should get only old version as HTML (with header which informs that you visit old version)

See page for `Stack_Overflow`

Current version:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow
or
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Stack_Overflow&oldid=1074237099

The oldest version:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Stack_Overflow&oldid=273483259

---

This way you could get HTML for all versions.

And if you use `@diff=...` with ID for different version (doesn't have to be current) then you can see also differences between two versions.

---

Current version:

[image]

The oldest version:

[image]